# Comparison of geolocation services

Tags: geolocation

I have been comparing results between maxmind.com Geoip2.city service and ipstack.com service.

Initially I had assumed that the maxmind service would be more accurate, based on a few various blog reviews.  And just from reading on the web, one could get the impression that maxmind is the gold standard.  When examining more closely, I saw the blog reviews stated "maxmind *claims* it has the most accurate results of any other location service," and it wasn't based on the blogger's experience or reference to independent analysis.

I checked out this page https://blog.maxmind.com/2014/01/31/who-has-the-most-accurate-ip-geolocation-data/ and found that maxmind was basing its claims on a single independent analysis done in 2011.

The reason I'm bringing this up is because I did a comparison between maxmind and ipstack for 171 ip addresses, located in various parts of the globe (though mostly US.)

28% of the results had mismatches between the two for country, region, city and/or postal code

32% of the maxmind results had values missing* for region, city and/or postal code

5% of the ipstack results had values missing* for region, city and/or postal code

100% of the results had differing location coordinates

The fact that maxmind was missing so many more values than ipstack (32% compared to 5%) made me wonder whether it is the more accurate service or not.

I would like to know if some folks can give me more insight based on their experience.

Here are some links to results of comparing the two:

IP addresses with inconsistencies flagged and described (excluding location coordinates):

http://kevinallasso.org/geoip/inconsistencies.txt

More detailed comparison containing results for each method:

http://kevinallasso.org/geoip/geoip_comparison.txt

EDIT: *Note, values were only counted missing if the opposing vendor had a value for that field.  If values were missing from both vendors, they were not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Maxmind and IP2Location are generally the industry leader in geolocation technology since 20 years ago. You can find the accuracy table published in their web site.

IPstack is a new player and I don't have much experience with.